# Is it possible to input spark df as a direct input for LightGBM?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, lightgbm

Is there any way to implement a spark data frame directly  as a input to the LightGBM algorithm without converting it to pandas data-frame?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this help : Apache Spark users can use [SynapseML](https://aka.ms/spark) for machine learning workflows with LightGBM. This project is not maintained by LightGBM’s maintainers. Source: [STFW](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parallel-Learning-Guide.html#apache-spark)